# Output of getchar

Tags: c

```
    int ch;
    do
    {
            ch = getchar();
            printf("ch = %d\n",ch);
    }while(ch != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

In this case the output for input 1234 is

```
    ch = 49
    ch = 50
    ch = 51
    ch = 52
    ch = 10
```

But on giving it like this

```
    char chs[100] = {0};
    unsigned int u = 0;
    int sign = 1,k=0;
    if(scanf("%[- 0-9]",&chs[0])== 1)
    {
             int ch;
             do
             {
              ch = getchar();
              printf("ch =  %d\n",ch);
             }while(ch != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

In this case output for input = 1234 is

```
    ch =10
```

Why is this happening here ???
Can someone please explain ... Why isn't the output same as before ??

How scanf is exactly working here ?

Comment: You already consumed the 1234 characters in the call to scanf so all that's left is the end of line character (LF = 10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call to `scanf` reads data from the stream. When you later try to read from the stream again by using `getchar` the characters that were read by `scanf` have already been consumed and are not read again.

Also, see the documentation for [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) for valid values of the format string.

Comment: Further, scanf is probably grabbing a whole line.  This code is broken, don't use both scanf and getchar.